# What is the right way to insert a line of code into a moodle module?

Tags: moodle

I have a the need to add a single line of code to locallib.php in the \mod\lti directory . ('custom_user' => $USER->username,)

```
$requestparams = array(
        'resource_link_id' => $instance->id,
        'resource_link_title' => $instance->name,
        'resource_link_description' => $instance->intro,
        'user_id' => $USER->id,
        'roles' => $role,
        'context_id' => $course->id,
        'context_label' => $course->shortname,
        'context_title' => $course->fullname,
        'launch_presentation_locale' => current_language()
    );


$requestparams = array(
        'resource_link_id' => $instance->id,
        'resource_link_title' => $instance->name,
        'resource_link_description' => $instance->intro,
        'user_id' => $USER->id,

        'custom_user' => $USER->username,

        'roles' => $role,
        'context_id' => $course->id,
        'context_label' => $course->shortname,
        'context_title' => $course->fullname,
        'launch_presentation_locale' => current_language()
    );
```

Is there a right way to do this? Looking at plugins, it seems that they are for adding whole new  functions, not just patching individual existing code.

Answer (score 0):

Just having a look at the module - haven't come across it before.

There are custom parameters but they look like literal values.

I would say its okay to put that code in. Although I would probably add // CUSTOM before and after the mod.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm kind of looking for the semi-official way that patches are done in Moodle.  Maybe something or someway that would also indicate or prevent maintenance from over ridding the patch?